# phpMyAdmin error: I am seeing errors in user accounts

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is my first xampp installation. In phpMyAdmin I am seeing following screen:

[image: Here is screen shot]

> ave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146:
>
> @Z() mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPAVTHD@@@Z() mysqld.exe!?
>
> TIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYS
>
> see``, `Routine_name`, `Routine_type`) VALUES("ma_test_host"
>
> umm last_update in table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" is BIN
>
> x_threads=501 thread_count=2 It is possible that mysql co
>
> exe!my_security_attr_free() mysql.exe!simple_key_cache_rea
>
> abort. Query (0x106e2f50): FLUSH PRIVILEGES Connection ID
>
> 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CR
>
> iv`(`host`,`Db`,`User`,`Routine_name`,`Routine_type`) VA
>
> ,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_c
>
> RROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run m
>
> b50 InnoDB: Error: Column last_update in table "mysql"."inno
>
> localhost
>
> or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunc
>   127.0.0.1 DB: Error: Column last_update in table "mysql"."innodb_table e '.\mysql\procs_priv.MYI'; try to repair it 151101 21:18:0
>   md_resignal@@UBE?AW4enum_sql_command@@XZ() mysqld.exe!?ha_i

I googled and found this [link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,45994,46038) but when am going to mysql website then there I am seeing 5.7x version

**UPDATE:**
I installed Xampp and I can see localhost. The Xampp starts apache + MySQL with no errors but when I click ==>phpMyAdmin ==> User Accounts then I was seeing aforementioned error.

Today when I restarted my laptop and again gone to phpMyAdmin==> user accounts then I am seeing SQL error:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv`) ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host` ASCrr
```

> Error
>       Static analysis:
>
> ```
> 5 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 51)
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 108)
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 174)
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 241)
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 306)
> SQL query: Documentation
>
> (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
> ```
>
> `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv`) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv`) ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host`
>   ASC LIMIT 0, 25
>
> ```
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #126 - Incorrect key file for table '.\mysql\user.MYI'; try to repair it
> ```

**UPDATE-1:**
I again restarted and seeing the following:

> Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261  mysqli_query():
>   (HY000/1030): Got error 9 "Bad file descriptor" from storage
>   engine MyISAM
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query( object, string
>   'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT 1', integer 0, )
>   .\libraries\DatabaseInterface.class.php#246:
>   PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery( string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` LIMIT
>   1', object, integer 0, ) .\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#46:
>   PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(string 'SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db`
>   LIMIT 1') .\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php#395:
>   PMA_checkRequiredPrivilgesForAdjust()
>   .\libraries\List_Database.class.php#17:
>   require_once(.\libraries\check_user_privileges.lib.php)
>   .\libraries\PMA.php#17:
>   require_once(.\libraries\List_Database.class.php)
>   .\libraries\common.inc.php#1089: include_once(.\libraries\PMA.php)
>   .\server_privileges.php#12: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
>   Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Why this question is down voted by -5. What I did wrong?

Comment: I suspect it's because there's nothing here we can use to help you. It looks like there's a load of error messages that have been imported into your database, but we've no idea where those might have come from. You might want to ask this on ServerFault instead - I'd suggest adding information on how you're trying to install the software. Also, you've tagged this as mysql-python - does that have anything to do with how you're installing it? Otherwise, what is the tag for?

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry to attach mysql-python tag. I removed it

Comment: I don't know enough DBA stuff to be able to help, but things like `Bad file descriptor` and `Incorrect key file for table` suggest that there's an issue with the disk. I'd suggest that you run something to check the integrity of the drive (scandisk in Windows) and see what that has to say. I'd also suggest again that you ask this on ServerFault, if it is indeed a disk issue

Comment: I just uninstalled and re-installed as d:/php/xamp and problem fixed. Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem I found is that windows 8.1 is not allowing some programs to change c:/programs.. folders.

I re-installed on my D: drive by creating a folder say D:/PHP/xampp and its started working fine